# Table View Data Source not showing all the rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am a seasoned web and Android developer and am teaching myself iPhone development on my MacBook running xCode 8.2 using the book Beginning iPhone Development with Swift 2. I am running into issues converting the examples in the book to Swift 3, but have been able to deal with most of them.

The tables are not going well, however. I have converted all of the methods I can figure out, but I can't get all of the table data to show on any of the examples. Here is my code:

```
//
//  RootViewController.swift
//  Fonts
//
//  Created by Thomas Hehl on 12/21/16.
//

import UIKit

class RootViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var familyNames: [String]!
    private var cellPointSize: CGFloat!
    private var favoritesList: FavoritesList!
    private static let familyCell = "FamilyName"
    private static let favoritesCell = "Favorites"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        familyNames = (UIFont.familyNames as [String]).sorted()
        let preferredTableViewFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
        cellPointSize = preferredTableViewFont.pointSize
        favoritesList = FavoritesList.sharedFavoritesList
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = cellPointSize

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fontForDisplay(atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIFont? {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let familyName = familyNames[ indexPath.row]
            let fontName = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName).first
            return fontName != nil ? UIFont(name: fontName!, size: cellPointSize) : nil
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return the number of sections
        return favoritesList.favorites.isEmpty ? 1 : 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section == 0 ? familyNames.count : 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return section == 0 ? "All Font Families" : "My Favorite Fonts"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            // the font names list
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RootViewController.familyCell, for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.font = fontForDisplay(atIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = familyNames[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = familyNames[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            //the favorites list
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RootViewController.favoritesCell, for: indexPath)
        }
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Unfortunately, even though that familyNames contains 75 entries, the table is only showing the first screenful. Here is the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Table]

As you can see, the scrollbar's all the way at the bottom, but that's not nearly all of the fonts.

Comment: Tried your code and I can see all the fonts by using the vertical scrollbar. What is your concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**EDIT** - After chat, it appears the problem is merely that the OP doesn't know how to scroll. The OP sent me the actual project, I ran it, and it works just fine.]

Your code works fine. I literally just copied and pasted your code into the Master-Detail template, made a few adjustments (commenting out the second section stuff because you didn't supply any info about it), and got this:

[image]

Comment: I am using the Single View Application and modifying it per instructions. Is there something else I need to do to get all of the data? My scrollbar only lets me scroll through the A's.

Comment: Or is this on an iPhone and it may just be the simulator?

Comment: Sorry, like I said, I'm new to this. What do you need to see as the setup for my storyboard? A screenshot of the whole storyboard setup? One of the things I don't like about this is that everything doesn't boil down to code, but there's magic connections that you make with the mouse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131301/discussion-between-the-thom-and-matt).