# Table View Controller Only Shows 15 Rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Going through Lynda's "Learn Swift 2: The Basics" course.  Currently running into a problem with my table views.

For instance: Despite the fact I've set the NumberOfRowsInSection function to 31, the app will only show 15 rows.  Here's the code I'm running:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DaysTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 31
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Basic")!

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: your code is perfectly fine. I checked it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/79u3uxo7eul28zp/tableView.zip?dl=0
Check  this

Comment: scroll the tableView, or if your see is not this tableView.

Comment: Isn't the problem merely that you don't know how to scroll? See my answer to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41293541/341994

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is wrong with your code. I already tested it too.

Check these few things: Did you run the app in iPhone 6 without navigation bar? Does the tableview scrolls? Did you disable the user interaction?

And also, try cleaning the project and run it again.